# Optimise filtering lists in Python 2.7

Tags: python, generator, python-2.7

I need to filter a large lists several times, but I'm concerned with both simplicity of code and execution efficiency. To give an example:

```
all_things # huge collection of all things

# inefficient but clean code
def get_clothes():
    return filter(lambda t: t.garment, allThings)

def get_hats():
    return filter(lambda t: t.headgear, get_clothes())
```

I'm concerned that I'm iterating over the clothes list when in fact it has already been iterated over. I also want to keep the two filter operations separate, as they belong to two different classes, and I do not want to duplicate the first lambda function in the hats class.

```
# efficient but duplication of code
def get_clothes():
    return filter(lambda t: t.garment, allThings)

def get_hats():
    return filter(lambda t: t.headgear and t.garment, allThings)
```

I have been investigating generator functions, as they seemed like the way to go, but I haven't as yet figure out how.

Comment: If you're worried about performance, did you **test** performance?

Comment: I would have if I thought it was not obvious.

Comment: "obvious" is a dangerous word when it comes to performance.

Comment: tested: from my crude test where clothes are about 30% of the full list, the reduction in execution time is about 40%. Pretty solid.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

First of all using `filter`/`lambda` combination is going to be deprecated. Current functional programming style is described in [Python Functional Programming HOWTO](http://docs.python.org/howto/functional.html).

Secondly, if you concerned with efficiency, rather than construct lists, you should return [generators](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/classes.html#generators). In this case they  are simple enough to use [generator expressions](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0289/).

```
def get_clothes():
    return (t for t in allThings if t.garment)

def get_hats():
    return (t for t in get_clothes() if t.headgear)
```

Or if you'd prefer, true generators (allegedly more pythonic):

```
def get_clothes():
    for t in allThings:
       if t.garment:
           yield t

def get_hats():
    for t in get_clothes():
        if t.headgear:
            yield t
```

If for some reason, sometimes you need `list` rather than `iterator`, you can construct list   by simple casting:

```
hats_list = list(get_hats())
```

Note, that above will **not** construct list of clothes, thus efficiency is close to your duplicate code version.

Comment: 1) The ``filter/lambda`` combination is not deprecated.  2) PEP 8 advises against returning an generator expression -- those should be consumed in the same scope whether they were created -- used a regular generator instead.  3).  If a list is what is needed, the OP should use a list comprehension rather than *list* wrapped around a genexp.

Comment: @RaymondHettinger: 1) it's not yet formally deprecated because of strong opposition, but it's been considered for dropping for more than  7 years now. 2)  haven't really found anything relevant to that in PEP-8 3) if and only if he _always_ needs list.

Comment: @vartec: one example why returning a genexp is dangerous: http://programmaticallyspeaking.com/?p=471. Your `get_hats` etc should really be generators themselves (`for t... if t.headgear: yield t`) rather than return genexps. // Seems already fixed.

Comment: @thg435: Fair enough, but like I've said in my answer, _in this particular case_, generator expressions are ok. In the example you link to, it's more of an issue with using closures, it doesn't really matter that the closure in this case is an generator expression.

Comment: Personally, I *sometimes* find the `filter/map/reduce` easier to read than the equivalent list comprehensions or loops. In the OP's case, a listcomp would have been simpler and easier to read, but that's not *always* the case.

Comment: The link in the comments above is broken, but probably should reference http://programmaticallyspeaking.com/generator-combined-with-withusing-statement-python-vs-c.html

Answer (score 5):

I was looking for similar filtering of lists but wanted to have a slightly different format to what was presented here.

The `get_hats()` call above is good but limited in its reuse.  I was looking for something more like `get_hats(get_clothes(all_things))`, where you can specify a source `(all_things)`, and then as few or as many levels of filters `get_hats()`, `get_clothes()` as you want.

I found a way to do that with generators:

```
def get_clothes(in_list):
    for item in in_list:
        if item.garment:
            yield item

def get_hats(in_list):
    for item in in_list:
        if item.headgear:
            yield item
```

This can then be called by:

```
get_hats(get_clothes(all_things))
```

I tested the original solutions, vartec's solution and this additional solution to see the efficiency, and was somewhat surprised by the results.  Code as follows:

Setup:

```
class Thing:
    def __init__(self):
        self.garment = False
        self.headgear = False

all_things = [Thing() for i in range(1000000)]

for i, thing in enumerate(all_things):
    if i % 2 == 0:
        thing.garment = True
    if i % 4 == 0:
        thing.headgear = True
```

Original solutions:

```
def get_clothes():
    return filter(lambda t: t.garment, all_things)

def get_hats():
    return filter(lambda t: t.headgear, get_clothes())

def get_clothes2():
    return filter(lambda t: t.garment, all_things)

def get_hats2():
    return filter(lambda t: t.headgear and t.garment, all_things)
```

My solution:

```
def get_clothes3(in_list):
    for item in in_list:
        if item.garment:
            yield item

def get_hats3(in_list):
    for item in in_list:
        if item.headgear:
            yield item
```

vartec's solution:

```
def get_clothes4():
    for t in all_things:
       if t.garment:
           yield t

def get_hats4():
    for t in get_clothes4():
        if t.headgear:
            yield t
```

Timing code:

```
import timeit

print 'get_hats()'
print timeit.timeit('get_hats()', 'from __main__ import get_hats', number=1000)

print 'get_hats2()'
print timeit.timeit('get_hats2()', 'from __main__ import get_hats2', number=1000)

print '[x for x in get_hats3(get_clothes3(all_things))]'
print timeit.timeit('[x for x in get_hats3(get_clothes3(all_things))]',
                    'from __main__ import get_hats3, get_clothes3, all_things',
                    number=1000)

print '[x for x in get_hats4()]'
print timeit.timeit('[x for x in get_hats4()]',
                    'from __main__ import get_hats4', number=1000)
```

Results:

```
get_hats()
379.334653854
get_hats2()
232.768362999
[x for x in get_hats3(get_clothes3(all_things))]
214.376812935
[x for x in get_hats4()]
218.250688076
```

The generator expressions appear to be slightly faster, the difference in time between my and vartec's solutions are probably just noise.  But I prefer the flexibility of being able to apply whatever filters are required in whatever order.

Answer (score 4):

To do it in one pass only (pseudocode):

```
clothes = list()
hats = list()
for thing in things:
    if thing is a garment:
        clothes.append(thing)
        if thing is a hat:
            hats.append(thing)
```

To do it in one big pass and one smaller pass (list comprehensions):

```
clothes = [ x for x in things if x is garment ]
hats = [ x for x in clothes if x is hat ]
```

If you want to create the *entire list* there's no point using a generator expression for lazy evaluation, because you're not going to be lazy.

If you only want to deal with a few things at a time, or if you're memory-constrained, use @vartec's generator solution.

Comment: you may want to fix `thing in things` usage

Comment: @okm: Not seeing it, sorry - can you elaborate?

Comment: I mean `[thing in clothes if thing is hat]` is not syntactic-correct, isn't it?